# Are there any open source codes that can generate LAMMPS potentials from DFT calculations?

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, lammps

Are there any opensource and freely distributed codes available which can be used to develop classical potentials for LAMMPS?

The [MEAMfit](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465515001964) code is free and opensource, but the input needs to be from VASP. Because of this, the tool is not actually available for someone without access to VASP.

I am looking to work with Heusler materials containing elements such as Zr, Ni, Ir, Sn etc.

Comment: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8932/what-are-the-open-source-or-software-code-that-can-generate-potentials/8933?noredirect=1#comment18673_8933 check this answer, it might be helpful

Comment: MEAMfit supports VASP, CASTEP and PWscf

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have a look at the [Open KIM](https://openkim.org) platform. It [supports](https://www.google.com/search?q=lammps%20site%3Aopenkim.org) LAMMPS potentials.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. OpenKIM creates LAMMPS-compatible potentials. But @PBH wanted to know codes that help create the potential from DFT calculations. It's possible I missed something - does OpenKIM have tools to help create new potentials?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison I checked, but I did not find any tools to create a new potential. Seems like the only remaining option is to find someone with a VASP license.

Comment: Please see https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8932/30